# How to configure an Azure Function to use Azure B2C in an Azure Resource Manager Template?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template in which I am configuring a Function App.

Here is a sample of my ARM template that deals with the Function App:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "name": "MyAzureFunctionName",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "dependsOn": [
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('nameWithDashes'))]",
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
         "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', 'MyAzureFunctionName')]",
         "httpsOnly": true,
         "siteConfig": {
             "appSettings": [
                 {
                     ...
                 }]
         }
     }
}
```

I am trying to configure my Azure Function to use Azure B2C for authorization. I am following the [existing instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-06-01/sites/config-authsettingsv2) but I fail to get the expected results. For instance, in the sample below, I am simply trying to activate the App Service Authentication:

```
{
     "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
     "name": "[concat('MyAzureFunctionName', '/authsettingsV2')]",
     "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
     "dependsOn": [
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', 'MyAzureFunctionName')]"
     ],
     "properties": {
         "enabled": "true"
     }
}
```

Nothing else is specified in this configuration since everything else is optional. I just wanted to see if I was poking at the right thing. Here is the Authorization / Authentication page after I ran the ARM template:

[image]

The configuration appears as if it was broken.

**Question**

How can I configure my Function App to use Azure B2C in an Azure Resource Manager Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532868/configuration-authentication-with-azure-ad-for-azure-app-service-with-arm-templa).

This example works fine for my apps (including Azure Functions):

```
{
                "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                "name": "web",
                "type": "config",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "siteAuthEnabled": "[parameters('enableAadAuthentication')]",
                    "siteAuthSettings": {
                      "clientId": "[parameters('aadClientId')]",
                      "issuer": "[parameters('aadIssuerUrl')]",
                      "isAadAutoProvisioned": false
                    }
                }
            }
```

For the values for B2C, you can add the information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788198/does-the-azure-app-service-authentication-module-suport-azure-aad-b2c):

- `aadClientId`: Your applicationId
- `enableAadAuthentication`: true
- `aadIssuerUrl`: Metadata endpoint URL. You can find it if you look at the signIn policy in the Azure Portal. An example: `https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1A_signup_signin`